# Discord.py bot status not showing

Tags: python, discord

So, when i was trying to add a status to my discord python bot, it wouldn't show up on discord, when running the code no errors would show up, it's just that the status wouldn't show itself.

```
#Connection to discord
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print({client.user}, 'has connected to Discord!')
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name='~help'))
```

If anyone knows a fix to this please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import discord
import os
import config
import sys



client = discord.Client()



@client.event
async def on_ready():
        print({client.user}, 'has connected to Discord!')
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name='~help'))

client.run(config.token)                        #imports token from the config.py
```

I tried your code in my test bot and it was working totally fine. I have attached the screenshots below and the code above. Not sure why it wouldn't work for you. [This is my entire code and has nothing extra attached in between or at the end].

Note: import config has my token (so it isn't a necessary import)

[image]

[image]